# How do we validate emails in cloudpages?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, cloudpage, landing-page, email-validation

I am creating a two cloud pages. One cloud page has one email input field and two input submit fields, one for Ok and one for Cancel. When the user writes their email address in the input field, I want to run validation onClick of the OK button. I created a javascript function within my cloud page and called it on my OK button. For some reason, my validation isn't being called successfully. I tested email addresses without "@", ".", and without both "a" and ".". When I click the OK button, it redirects me to the next cloudpage where people can sign up for different event communications. How can I validate email correctly?

My code:

```
<script runat="server">
      function checkEmail() {
        var email = document.getElementById('txtEmail');
        var filter = /^([a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9\-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4)+$/;
        if (!filter.test(email.value)) {
          alert('Please provide a valid email address');
          email.focus;
          return false;
        }
      }
    </script>
```

Email Input

```
<input type="txtEmail" name="Email" value="%%emailaddr%%" data-field-type="Email" required="required" data-validation-message="Please provide your email address.">
```

OK Button

```
 <input type="submit" value="OK" onClick="checkEmail();">
```

Comment: I think you're confusing _server-side_ JavaScript and _client-side_ JavaScript. There are a ton of client-side validation methods and only a few server-side ones available in SFMC.

Comment: you need both server and client side validation for a proper validation. I've answered your question here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/293234/data-validation-for-cloud-page-forms/293269#293269